# Cant login on PhpLdapAdmin using admin user

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, openldap

im trying to configure an LDAP using slapd and [PhpLdapAdmin](https://github.com/leenooks/phpLDAPadmin) using the non-official version from github on my Ubuntu server.  the slapd and phpldapadmin works perfectly but i have a problem while login using the admin user from the slapd, phpldapadmin want to use email for login. but the slapd dont have a mail attribute for the admin user. so my question is how to give a mail attribute for admin user or is there any solution to login phpLdapAdmin?

Thanks for Reading my question, Here the screenshot of the login problem

[image]

[image]

The Second screenshot is when i input the email using admin@example.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ldapadd` to create a "normal" LDAP entry with this DN, with whatever attributes you like. The DN will retain its "superuser" privileges.

(However, once it becomes a normal entry, its password will be checked against the 'userPassword' attribute – no longer against the rootPW from configuration. So when you're creating this entry, don't forget to set a userPassword with help of `slappasswd`.)